# One of the famous weapon in WWII. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> My shield is thin, yet the shape makes it thick. 
>   People found hard to kill me, but animals can do that easily. 
>   I have so many teammates, while few of them do communicates. 
>   Having ears like Mickey Mouse, but not come from Disneyland.

What am I?

Comment: Love ww2 references so keep them coming

Comment: @SOakes Glad you like that, I will try my best!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer:

> It's the Russian T-34 model 1942 medium tank

*My shield is thin, yet the shape makes it thick.*

> The T-34 tanks were well known about their armour. They had a thin armour, but the engineers used a good angle (sloped armour), and the incoming projectiles often bounced off the tank.

*People found hard to kill me, but animals can do that easily.*

> I guess this is a reference of the German panzers. Hitler's tanks usually had a nickname like "[Tiger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tanks_in_World_War_II#Tiger_I)" or "[Panther](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tanks_in_World_War_II#Panther)". These tanks were well engineered and were great opponents of the Allies' tanks.

*I have so many teammates, while few of them do communicates.*

> Not all T-34 tanks had proper radio systems – especially the early versions – so communicating with teammates was hard. ["A lack of properly installed and shielded radios – if they existed at all – ..."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-34).

*Having ears like Mickey Mouse, but not come from Disneyland.*

> There were more versions of T tanks manufactured by the soviets which could be the "winner" of this riddle; but the T-34 model 1942 had two hatches, making it look like Mickey Mouse. [Reference](http://www.tanks-encyclopedia.com/ww2/soviet/soviet_T34-76.php): "These can be identified by their hexagonal turrets and the open twin “Mickey Mouse ears” hatches."

Comment: That is one hell of a reference.

Comment: Nice try and correct answer! What you're still thinking is a bit more detailed, but Wikipedia has it.

Comment: @ShaneHsu Okay, I'll try to find it.

Comment: @ShaneHsu Updated that part.

Comment: That is a clear & complete reference, well done!

Comment: @ShaneHsu It was a good riddle. I remembered when I read my WW2 books as a children... Good memories. :)

Comment: @Lasoloz So glad you like it!